# Bounded and weakly bounded sets in top. vector spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Consider a locally convex topological vector space V over the complex numbers. Is it true that every weakly bounded subset of V is indeed bounded? If not, what additional requirements are needed for this to hold? Perhaps someone has a reference, I was not able to find something in the literature.

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,

Ralf

Answer (score 8):

Theorem 3.18 in the excellent book by Rudin "**Functional Analysis**" says: *In a locally convex space $X$, every weakly bounded set is originally bounded, and vice versa.* The proof is based on the Banach-Alaoglu theorem (well, no surprise) and Baire's category theorem.

Comment: What's "originally bounded"?  I've never heard of that one!

Comment: It means "bounded in the original topology"

Comment: Of course in the case where X is not just a LCTVS but a Banach space then this is the Uniform Boundedness theorem (a.k.a. Banach-Steinhaus, more or less)

Comment: @Yemon: that's what worries me a little about this answer.  Banach-Steinhaus is a Big Theorem and I don't think that it holds for all LCTVS (does it even hold for incomplete nvs?).  Unfortunately, I'm not in my office so can't check my sources, but I want to say something like "X needs to be barrelled", but that might only be to do with the space of functions on X, not X itself.

Comment: @Andrew: a subset $E$ of a topological vector space $X$ is (originally) bounded if to every neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $X$ corresponds a number $s > 0$ such that $E \subset tV$ for every $t > s$. I'm sorry, I should have stated the definition that I use in my answer, but I think, this is the common definition if you just have topological vector spaces.

Comment: There also is a variant of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem as follows: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological vector spaces, $K$ is a *compact convex* set in $X$, $\Gamma$ is a collection of continuous linear mappings of $X$ to $Y$, and the orbits $\Gamma(x)$ (i.e. the set of all $\Lambda(x)$ for all $\Lambda \in \Gamma$) are bounded subsets of $Y$, for every $x \in K$. Then there is a bounded $B \subset Y$ such that $\Lambda(K) \subset B$ for every $\Lambda \in \Gamma$. (Theorem 2.9 in Rudin - the thing I like about this book is that it contains theorems in its outmost generality).

Comment: @Ulrich: it was the "originally" that was confusing me, but I agree that having the definition in the answer would have helped.  I also withdraw my anxiety since Banach-Steinhaus applies to mapping spaces, say from E to F, and all the conditions are on E.  We can (if we want to crack a walnut with a sledgehammer) apply it to a LCTVS simply by taking E = R, in which case all the conditions are easily seen to be satisfied.  Hence weakly bounded implies bounded.  This clearly isn't the simplest proof, though!

Comment: @YemonChoi, doesn't this just follow from a corollary to the Hahn-Banach theorem, if X is a Banach space? My line of thought is as follows. We show that if a set is not bounded, then it is not weakly bounded. For every $n$, there exists $x$ with $\lVert x \rVert \geq n$. But by a corollary to the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists a functional $x^\ast$ with $\lVert x^\ast \rVert = 1$ and $| x^\ast(x) | = \lVert x \rVert \geq n$.

Comment: @Rauni that is not the definition of weakly bounded. Saying $S$ is weakly bounded means: for each $x^*$, the set $\{ x^*(x) : x\in S\}$ is bounded. In your argument, you have picked an $x$ and then picked an $x^*$. You need to show there exists a single $x^*$ and a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ with $|x^*(x_n)| \to \infty$.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thank You for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

This is direct consequence of the **Mackey Theorem**: Having a dual pair (V,V') with V' as the dual of the locally convex space V, the bounded sets on V under any dual topology are identical. A dual topology on V is a locally convex topology $\tau$ such that (V,$\tau$)' = V'.

As the original and the weak topology give the same dual, the bounded sets are identical.